# How to fetch data an array instead of an object in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im not 100% sure that this is the problem, but Im using the fetch method to grab data from this link https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people . And then im trying to use the `.map` function on it. Instead of working, I get a `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): jedis.map is not a function` error.

When I console logged `jedis` I got everything you see in that link, like count: 87, next: "https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/?page=2", etc.

Im assuming that the error means that `jedis` is actually a object and not an array. But again, im not totally sure thats the reason. If it is, how can I access the data so that `jedis` is an array and not an object

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CardList from './CardList'

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      jedis: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people').then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(jedi => this.setState({jedis: jedi}));
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <CardList jedis={this.state.jedis}/>

      )
  }

}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from './Card'

const CardList = ({ jedis }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                //console.log(jedis)
                jedis.map((jedi, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Card
                            key = {i}
                            name = {jedi.name}
                            height = {jedi.height}
                            mass = {jedi.mass}
                        />
                        )

                })

            } 
        </div>

    )   


}


export default CardList;
```

Heres the API im using incase anyone is wondering 
http://swapi.py4e.com/

Comment: `jedis.results.map`?

Comment: Already tried that but it didnt work. Just got a 
```TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined``` error

Comment: this is because you are initialising state as `this.state = { jedis: [] }`. Change that to `this.state = { jedis: { results: [] } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response of the API,

Change your `CardList` component props to:

```
<CardList jedis={this.state.jedis.results} />
```

Also, then you need to change your state initialisation to:

```
this.state = {
  jedis: {
    count: 0,
    previous: null,
    next: null,
    results: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh i see now what you meant from before. Yes this worked great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep adding to the array on every fetch, you will want to use the spread operator and `previousState`.

```
fetch('https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people').then(resp => resp.json())
.then(jedi => { 

    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        jedis: [...previousState.jedis, jedi.results],
      };
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Actually you need to convert the response object to Array and you will be good to run `map` on it. Below is an example assume you get numbers as keys, if your obj response keys are not numbers but regular strings you can replace `Number(key)` with `key` in return statement.

`var obj = { "1": 5, "2": 7, "3": 0, "4": 0};
   var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { 
        return [Number(key), obj[key]]; 
    });`